# Random number in a loop, how do stop it from getting a new number every frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

Learning Action script and programming so I apologize that the solution is simple, I just don't know what it is. What I want to happen is to pass objects through that I want to fall down the screen. I pass the object in through e:Event (which comes from an event listener on the stage) and speed which gets a random number between a high and low value.

When I run it, it of course gets a new random number every frame. (because its called by an Event.ENTER_FRAME

How do I go about this to accomplish my goal?

Here is my code:

```
private function moveIt(e:Event, speed):void
    {
        if ( e.currentTarget.y <= 400 )
        {
            var objSpeed = speed;
            e.currentTarget.y = e.currentTarget.y + speed;
            trace("speed = "+ speed);
        }
        else
        {
             //Do other stuff
        }
    }//moveit
```

as requested, here are the other pieces of code that are relevant:

random number

```
private function randomNum(high, low):Number
    {
        var randNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1 + high - low))+low;
        return randNum;
    }
```

called here

```
iconPsd.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate)
```

and then through here (uneeded but this was my try)

```
private function animate(e:Event):void
    {
        var speed:Number = randomNum(55, 0.1);
        moveIt(e, speed);
        trace ("speed in animate = "+ speed);

    }//animate
```

Comment: You should post the part of your code which generates the random number speed.

Comment: I've added the code. I get no error, I just need to know how to properly use a random number in a loop so it doesnt get a new random number every frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `var speed:Number = randomNum(55, 0.1);` out of the animate function.

And write it like this:

```
iconPsd.speed = randomNum(55, 0.1);
iconPsd.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);

private function animate(e:Event):void
    {
        moveIt(e);
        trace ("speed in animate = "+ e.currentTarget.speed);

    }//animate

private function moveIt(e:Event):void
    {
        if ( e.currentTarget.y <= 400 )
        {
            e.currentTarget.y = e.currentTarget.y + e.currentTarget.speed;
            trace("speed = "+ e.currentTarget.speed);
        }
        else
        {
             //Do other stuff
        }
    }//moveit
```

Here you assign the speed as a property of the `iconPsd` object outside of the `enterFrame`, but can still use it inside the `enterFrame`.

You can also compress it to just this:

```
iconPsd.speed = randomNum(55, 0.1);
iconPsd.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);

private function animate(e:Event):void
    {
        if ( e.currentTarget.y <= 400 )
        {
            e.currentTarget.y = e.currentTarget.y + e.currentTarget.speed;
            trace("speed = "+ e.currentTarget.speed);
        }
        else
        {
             //Do other stuff
        }
    }//animate
```

Comment: Prefect, thank you! This worked exactly as I wanted it to. I didn't know about the speed property.

Comment: @jonshariat Glad it worked for you :), but speed isn't a default property, you can replace speed with anything. Because iconPsd is an object you can add any property you want to it (think of it as storing variables you can access using the object as the scope).